# How to update data in an ets bag?

Tags: erlang, bag, ets

ets:insert can be used to update data in an ets set, but how about a bag? Do we have to update by match_delete or select_delete first and then insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of a bag doesn't make sense if updates are going to be required. Given that `ets:update_element/3` explicitly doesn't support bags, it seems evident that delete then write is your only option.

Comment: Yep, seems that delete then insert is the only choice if I have to stick with bag. I'm thinking if using a set with the help of an extra index table is helpful in terms of performance, will try.